# iOS: Bluetooth Sharing

Tags: ios, ios-bluetooth

I see there is a "Bluetooth Sharing" section under iOS 7/8's Privacy settings:[image: Bluetooth Sharing]

I have a couple questions about this:

1. What framework is used to access this?
2. Is this iOS to iOS device only, or can it be iOS to Android, or iOS to some other peripheral?
3. Is there anything else required, other than that framework, such as GameCenter or HomeKit; to implement the framework from Question 1?
4. Would use of it require a Private API?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apps that specify one of the two [Bluetooth background modes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW1) (Central or peripheral) will appear in this list.

Details on acting as a Bluetooth Low Energy peripheral or central are contained in the [Core Bluetooth Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html)

Bluetooth Low Energy can be used between any compatible device, including iOS and Android.

Comment: Thank you. I simply wanted to know where to go as a starting point.